# jquery - Increment attribute by set value

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function that has been running well until recently.

```
//Calculate width of slider container
var calc_width = 200 * $('.side_list_cont').length;
$("#op_slide").width(calc_width);


//Calculation for when to decrease margin for slide effect
$('#op_right').click(function(){
    var slidewidth = parseInt($('#op_slide').css('width'),10),
        getslideleft = parseInt($('#op_slide').css('margin-left'),10),
        slideleft = ((getslideleft - 200)*-1);
    if ( slideleft >= slidewidth ) {
    }
    else {
        $('#op_slide').animate({'margin-left': '-=200px'}, 200);
    }
});


//Calculation for when to increase margin for slide effect
$('#op_left').click(function(){
    var slidewidth = $('#op_slide').css('width'),
        slideleft = $('#op_slide').css('margin-left');
    if (slideleft == '0px') {
    }
    else {
        $('#op_slide').animate({'margin-left': '+=200px'}, 200);
    } 
});
```

I used to work great.  Then all of a sudden, it's not incrementing the margin-left value, but just changing it to either `200px` or `-200px`.  When looking at jQuery's docs on `.animate`, their example on this increment method works as it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you recently upgrade to jQuery 1.10.0? If so, the relative incremental animation issue (e.g. `.animate({'margin-left': '+=200px'}`) was [a bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13939) in that version that was just fixed today in 1.10.1.

See: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/30/jquery-1-10-1-and-2-0-2-released/ and http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13939

Comment: Yeah, I'm linked to latest.  It's an old Joomla build that uses a module. ...ugh.