# Jquery animate works first time, but not after that

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

this is a live example of the problem: http://www.igabiba.si
If you change the featured picture by clicking on the > button (next) the animation fires correctly the first time, but not on the later tries. Later on it just skips the animation and positions at the final position after the set amount of time.

Strangely enough, the animation of the previous button works flawlessly.

This is the part of the code that animates the background picture (all code is visible in the source):

```
if (mode == 'prev') {

                  $('#take_div').animate({
                    left: '-2000px',
                  }, 500, function() {
                    if (takeFields[2] != '') {
                        $('#take_link').attr('href',takeFields[2]);
                    }
                    $('#take_div').css('background',takeFields[1]+' url(/media/uploads/gTakeover/'+takeFields[0]+') no-repeat center top');
                    $('#take_div').css('left','');
                    $('#take_div').css('right','-2000px');
                    $('#take_div').animate({
                        right: '0px',
                    }, 500);
                  });

              } else {

                $('#take_div').animate({
                    right: '-=2000',
                  }, 500, function() {
                    if (takeFields[2] != '') {
                        $('#take_link').attr('href',takeFields[2]);
                    }
                    $('#take_div').css('background',takeFields[1]+' url(/media/uploads/gTakeover/'+takeFields[0]+') no-repeat center top');
                    $('#take_div').css('right','');
                    $('#take_div').css('left','-2000px');
                    $('#take_div').animate({
                        left: '0px',
                    }, 500);
                  });

              }
```

I would appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js is the version i'm linking

Comment: I was asking which version because of a bug, but not realated to version you are using: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16849097/1414562

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the problem. It was a problem with the "left" property being set to 0px, after the first animation. The second time it ran it had changing "right" property but the left stayed at 0px, so instead of:

```
$('#take_div').animate({
                right: '-=2000',
              }, 500, function() {
                if (takeFields[2] != '') {
                    $('#take_link').attr('href',takeFields[2]);
                }
                $('#take_div').css('background',takeFields[1]+' url(/media/uploads/gTakeover/'+takeFields[0]+') no-repeat center top');
                $('#take_div').css('right','');
                $('#take_div').css('left','-2000px');
                $('#take_div').animate({
                    left: '0px',
                }, 500);
              });
```

I did this:

```
$('#take_div').stop().animate({
                    right: '-2000px',
                  }, 500, function() {
                    if (takeFields[2] != '') {
                        $('#take_link').attr('href',takeFields[2]);
                    }
                    $('#take_div').css('background',takeFields[1]+' url(/media/uploads/gTakeover/'+takeFields[0]+') no-repeat center top');
                    $('#take_div').css('right','');
                    $('#take_div').css('left','-2000px');
                    $('#take_div').stop().animate({
                        left: '0px',
                    }, 500, function () {
                        $('#take_div').css('left','auto');
                    });
                  });
```

Now it works smoothly. Thanks for all the help though guys.

Answer (score 1):

add in .stop() in front of all .animate() functions and see.

```
$('#take_div').stop().animate({
    right: '0px',
}, 500);
```

Comment: doesn't seem to help. Thanks for trying to help though

Comment: check your console error also, ... Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cmd' of undefined www.igabiba.si/:383 ...
carouFredSel: No element found for "#foo2". ...
The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating all.js:55

Comment: that isn't it, but thanks for pointing it out. Below is my answer.